# Is it possible to prevent death by parentheses?

Tags: language-agnostic, parentheses

Occasionally, I will write some code with way more parentheses than I like.

```
 if(!(new Day((((new Date()) / millisecondsPerDay) % 75)) instanceof oldDay))) { 
    // Bonus points if that condition made any sense to you
 }
```

It is hard to keep track of how many parentheses I need to put, especially when I'm not using an IDE that immediately tells me when something is wrong. In fact, I bet the above example doesn't match the parentheses correctly. I've been pegged with errors from death by parentheses more than I would like to admit.

I was wondering if there was a way to circumvent this. What techniques can I use to avoid having to wrap things with so many parentheses?

Are there any languages with a mechanism that prevent the need for so many parentheses? For example, I thought adding special characters that automaticall close parentheses and one that automatically opens them might help. (`<` and `>` in the following example)

```
if(!(new Day<new Date()) / millisecondsPerDay) % 75> instanceof oldDay>
```

Comment: `Are there any languages with a mechanism that prevent the need for so many parentheses?` Try Brainfuck, it has no parens at all! :)

Comment: Better too many parentheses than one set too few and getting kicked in the rump by some obscure operator precedence rule you forgot about.

Comment: @Alex It has square brackets `[]` which I sometimes have similar problems with.

Comment: @Alex Extended Brainfuck has parentheses which are like block of code :)

Comment: @Igoris Heh heh, I think "Extended Brainfuck" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @Alex Well that is true :) But that's not me who creates such kind of name for "programming" language :) By the way there is procedural brainfuck as well, as many more of brainfuck :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One viable alternative is to precompute the parenthesized values before the conditional loop. Take your code for example:

```
if(!(new Day((((new Date()) / millisecondsPerDay) % 75)) instanceof oldDay))) { 
    // Bonus points if that condition made any sense to you
 }
```

Let's start breaking it up.

```
Date d1 = new Date();
var factor1 = (d1 / millisecondsPerDay ) % 75;
Day day1 = new Day (factor1);

if (!day1 instanceof oldDay) {
// do something
}
```

Remember that code is written for humans to read and only afterwards for machines to execute. If you find giant conditionals, then start preprocessing them and break it up. If it takes more than a second to figure out what your condition is checking, then it's probably too long.

Comment: and with most modern compilers and the optimizing they do behind the scenes, the hard to read version and the easy to read version both compile down to the same executing code. Write code with consideration for those that follow.

Comment: Well not always you can write O(n^3) instead of O(n^2) on a very large set of data, O(n^3) may be more readable then other one, but then you should use Profiler to look for these problems. First of all you need to write not for speed, but for understandability !

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all i always like to refactor this kind of code. If i can, i extract part of expression to the variable (or function, whichever suites best), then you can make more sense to the code itself, and you would'nt need to make such a mess

```
bool isOldDay(int someFactor)
{
    if(someFactor instanceof oldDay) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

var today = new Date();
var particularFactor = today/millisecondsPerDay;
var someFactor = particularFactor % 75
var day = new Day(someFactor);


if(!isOldDay(day)) //Do something
```

**EDIT:** By the way if you want to do something without parentheses you can try something like this: [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Which you can make `5 + ((1 + 2) * 4) − 3` into this thing : `5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 -` .Of course this form may be very close to stack representation of calculations in compilators.

Comment: Please, `return someFactor instanceof oldDay;`

Comment: well you can return it if you want in another method like getOldDay, and there you check if it is instanceof oldDay, or not an oldDay instance in which case you can return null...

Answer (score 1):

If i follow:

```
var a = new Date() / millisecondsPerDay) % 75
var newDay = new Day(a);

if (! newDay instanceof oldDay) {
   //do something
}
```

If you can't read an inline logic... just put it on multiple line! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That many parens is a pretty good indication that

1. The author doesn't understand the operator precedence of the language. For instance, you've wrapped a constructor invocation `new Date()` in a completely redundant set of parentheses `(new Date())`. Unless your language is different than any normal language, that prefix `new` operator is going to bind tighter than almost any other operator.
2. The author doesn't care about understandability.

Make it more understandable, testable and maintainable. Somebody down the line (who might well be you, will thank you for it...or curse you for not doing so).

Some hints:

- Understand your language's operator precedence. Don't add parentheses without good reason. Somebody who does understand operator precedence has to spend some time figuring out **why** you put those parens in: are you doing something non-obvious here?
- Break the expression up. Use stack space (it's cheap).
- Compute each simple subexpression as an independent local variable, building on the previous ones.
- make the variable names reflect what they represent.

Then test only the final temporary. In your case, that looks to be a boolean.

Writing code like that makes it easy to under stand (there are no complex expression), it makes it easy to test (simple expressions is much easier to check for correctness). It makes it easier to identify/locate problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer to this is NO, because the whole point of all those parentheses is to avoid ambiguity in the expression. If you remove them, the expression may not be evaluated in the way that you think it will.

Ergo, if there was such a construct as `<>` to fix/add your missing parens, if may not add them in the place you were expecting it to.

Simple example (as if it were needed):

```
(90 / 100 - 1)
```

...will evaluate to either...

```
((90 / 100) - 1) // = -0.1
```

...or...

```
(90 / (100 - 1)) // = 0.90909090...
```

... and you have no real way to know which one it will be.

The only alternative is to move some of the parts outside your expression, store the results in variables so you can evaluate less in your expression.

Comment: In most cases there's an order of precedence that's followed more or less universally.   Especially in your example division always takes precedence over subtraction (in math and any sane programming language).  Given that the user of the language is aware of the order there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Davy8 Granted, but that still relies on a bug-free interpretter. For a very complicated expression, something might go wrong. I always work to the assumption that other peoples programs don't work properly - that way I account for everything that might ever go wrong, however unlikely. I would always use the (extra) parens. But you are correct in that there **should** be no ambiguity.