# Sql query can't get 3rd elseif value - Why?

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL query below won't output the $srchRegion && $srchCategory string if there are $_POST values for both. Why?

```
if (($srchRegion!='00') || ($srchRegion!='') && ($srchCategory=='00') || ($srchCategory=='')) {
    return $query .= "AND region='$srchRegion'";
} elseif (($srchRegion=='00') || ($srchRegion=='') && ($srchCategory!='00') || ($srchCategory!='')) {
    return $query .= "AND category='$srchCategory'";
} elseif (($srchRegion!='00') || ($srchRegion!='') && ($srchCategory!='00') || ($srchCategory!='')) {
    return $query .= "AND region='$srchRegion' AND category='$srchCategory'";
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209888/is-it-possible-to-prevent-death-by-parentheses - that's your problem in a nutshell. Try and use less parentheses, well over half of the ones you used don't need to be there, and it is actually causing your problem. The other part of your problem is summed up [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for all possible boolean values and cluttered if-else, why just keep on appending the where clause based on corresponding value populated.

```
if($srchRegion != '00' && $srchRegion != '') 
  $query .= " AND region='$srchRegion'";
if($srchCategory != '00' && $srchCategory != '')
  $query .= " AND category='$srchCategory'";
return $query;
```

So `$query` acts as query builder and it keeps on adding where clause based on $_POST values being set.

Comment: Thank you Sundar, that's nice, much simpler approach. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(($srchRegion!='00' || $srchRegion!='') && ($srchCategory=='00' || $srchCategory=='')){
return $query .= "AND region='$srchRegion'";
} elseif(($srchRegion=='00' || $srchRegion=='') && ($srchCategory!='00' || $srchCategory!='')){
return $query .= "AND category='$srchCategory'";
} elseif($srchRegion!='00' || $srchRegion!='') && ($srchCategory!='00' || $srchCategory!='')){
return $query .= "AND region='$srchRegion' AND category='$srchCategory'";
}
```

You haven't structured the if condition right. You check two OR conditions with one AND condition, so you'll need to put the OR conditions in brackets.

Comment: Sometimes one cannot see the wood for the Trees. Thanks that's 100% correct, works perfectly now.